# mysql_query WHERE `id` = '$user' && '$post'

Tags: php, mysql

so I have a mysql query that looks like this.

```
$copy = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `brain` WHERE `id` = '$user_screen_name' && '$posts['title']'");
```

I want the query to search for the id that is in the table where screen name and post title strings are matched and put the found id in a variable. How would I do this?

Comment: Please use mysqli and prepared statements your code is very insecure.

Comment: Read some mysql documentation. What you're asking is as basic as can be. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: i think you want `LIKE '%$var%'`

Comment: @PirateTube do not be insulting to those who are trying to help you. Folks will run from your questions like roaches run from light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, some warnings:

***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

[Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

---

To fix your query you need a separate `AND` condition for each item you want to filter against:

```
WHERE `id` = '$user_screen_name' 
AND `title` = '$posts["title"]'
```

Without seeing your table layout it would be hard to go much further but if you want the id in a variable you would do this *after* the query:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($copy);
```

Once done, `$row['id']` will be the variable containing the id.

Comment: Can you give me an example from my code example? Because right now I'm getting an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: Uh, that is what I did.

Comment: Receiving Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) I think it's because of the "'"" in "'$post["title"]'" from the query

Comment: Without being able to see your new code I'll point you here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them